# Angular, Init form inputs are invalid but value is valid

Tags: angular

I made an angular form with two inputs number and one select.
I fill these inputs with a model values, but the two numbers inputs is invalid and i need to click inside it to change it to valid.

I use inputs like this :

```
<input type="text"
  name="price"
  id="price"
  [(ngModel)]="chair.price"
  formControlName="price"
  class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
  [ngClass]="{
      'is-invalid': editPriceForm.controls['price'].invalid,
      'is-valid':editPriceForm.controls['price'].valid
   }"
/>
```

So in the initial render form, i get the good value in the inputs but the class of the input is 'is-invalid', and i don't know why. I try to trigget a markAllAsTouched but nothing change.

When i click inside the input, and click out, the class change to become valid.

Do you know if something is possible to tell to the form to be rechecked after filling data ?

Comment: You are mixing two different types of Angular's handling of forms. First, refactor your code to either `Template Driven Forms` by removing `formControlName`  and only use `[(ngModel)]` or by removing `[(ngModel)]` and only use `formControlName` so that your code is `Reactive Forms`

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem is if i remove the ngModel, when the value of my model change, it not too change in the view.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz so that I can help you better? When your model value changes you should update your `formControlName`  by using setValue() for example when you think your value has changed use `this.yourForm.controls.price.setValue('price changed');`

Comment: It is now working ! Thank you a lot for your help :) 
Can i contact you directly if I have another question or not ? (If yes, do you have skype or something else ?)

Comment: You can post an answer and i will validate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two different types of Angular's handling of forms. First, refactor your code to either Template Driven Forms by removing `formControlName` and only using `[(ngModel)]` or by removing `[(ngModel)]` and only use `formControlName` so that your code is Reactive Forms.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the code is always executing, without checking if the user made any changes for it to check. What you should do is the following:

```
    <input type="text"
      name="price"
      id="price"
      [(ngModel)]="chair.price"
      formControlName="price"
      class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
      [ngClass]="{
                  'is-invalid': editPriceForm.controls['price'].invalid && 
                                editPriceForm.controls['price'].touched
                  }"
    />
```

With what I added that was `editPriceForm.controls['price'].touched` the code is only executed if the user clicked on the input